# Heroku: Git fails to compile Node.js

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, gulp

0My last push to Heroku fails without giving much explanation.

node_modules has been properly added to .gitignore since day 1. Since last deploy,no changes to package.json have been initiated, no new module or bower component has been installed.

Is there any way to get more details from the log? -v doesn't seem to add anything. I'm a bit at a loss, any help would be tremendously welcome.

The error message:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Removing .DS_Store files
remote: -----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to inviewapp.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/xboardx.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

and here are the contents of package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xboardx",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "gzippo": "^0.2.0",

    "express": "^4.10.5",
    "morgan": "^1.5.0",
    "require-dir": "^0.1.0",

    "gulp": "^3.8.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^0.0.6",
    "gulp-cache": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-csso": "^0.2.6",
    "gulp-filter": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-flatten": "^0.0.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-inject": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.8.0",
    "gulp-karma": "^0.0.4",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^0.8.0",
    "gulp-minify-html": "^0.1.3",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-ng-html2js": "^0.1.6",
    "gulp-protractor": "^0.0.11",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-rev": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-rev-replace": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^0.7.3",
    "gulp-size": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-useref": "^1.0.0",
    "http-proxy": "^1.3.0",
    "main-bower-files": "^2.0.0",
    "protractor": "^1.4.0",
    "uglify-save-license": "^0.4.1",
    "wiredep": "^1.8.5",
    "chalk": "^0.4.0",
    "connect-modrewrite": "^0.7.9",
    "del": "^0.1.3",
    "jshint-stylish": "^0.4.0"

  },
  "devDependencies": {


    "browser-sync": "^1.3.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.1.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4"


  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Node 0.11.x is unstable and not supported by Heroku.

Change to:

```
`  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x"
  },
`
```

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#node-js-runtimes

Comment: My bad, 0.10.x was on the original config, changed to 0.11.x to try to force an engine update see if that made any difference. Both failed. Good point though.

Comment: Did you change the name by any chance?

Comment: no, i think it might have been a problem on Heroku's side, as the push finally resolved without any changes. Thanks!